# Send complex objects in json using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, http

im trying to send a nested json object using $http,  heres the json object what im talking about {"name":"toto", categori{"name":"titi":"codes":"1455"}}
This is an example, can anybody tell me how to do that!

Comment: {"name":"toto", "categories": {"name":"titi":"codes":"1455"}}  this is also fine

Comment: But how to send that using $http of angularjs,  could u give me an example please

Comment: what is the actual *issue*?  `$http` doesn't have specific requirements for data structures, other than that they are valid JSON....

Comment: Hi guys, i have a form in angularjs, with           name and category,  but the problem is when i      send this form using angularjs,  it sent like this:    {"name":"toto", "category":" toto"} but i dont want          this result,  i want the result as{"name":"toto", "category":{" name":"toto"}} how to achieve that please,  i want to mention that the name is a normal text field but category is select field.

Comment: it sounds like your binding is to `yourObject.category`, which makes `category` a string, but you want `category` to be an object.  I would try changing your binding to `yourObject.category.name` instead.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer,  but imagine this form:‹input type=text ng-model="article. Name"/› and ‹select ng-model="article.Category" ng-option="category.Id category.name for category in article.payloadcat› now how i can send the article object with the form above in first comment

Comment: as I mentioned, in the select, use `ng-model="article.Category.name"`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON values can be arrays, objects, or primitives (numbers or strings).

```
{
  "name": "toto",
  "categories": [
    {"name": "titi": "codes": "1455"},
    {"name": "tata": "codes": "1456"} //If more categories
  ]
}

var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  },
  data: {
    test: 'test'
  }
}

$http(req).then(function() {
  ..
}, function() {
  ..
});
```

In data we will send JSON data

Comment: But how to send that using $http of angularjs,  could u give me an example please

Comment: Edited answer pls check

Comment: Hi guys, i have a form in angularjs, with           name and category,  but the problem is when i      send this form using angularjs,  it sent like this:    {"name":"toto", "category":" toto"} but i dont want          this result,  i want the result as{"name":"toto", "category":{" name":"toto"}} how to achieve that please,  i want to mention that the name is a normal text field but category is select field.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, but imagine this form:‹input type=text ng-model="article. Name"/› and ‹select ng-model="article.Category" ng-option="category.Id category.name for category in article.payloadcat› now how i can send the article object with the form above in first comment